# Haxe Javascript: get and set property by its name without using Reflect

Tags: javascript, properties, haxe, tween

I want to be able to set and get a property value by its name without using the Reflect API.
I'm making some sort of a tween engine, animating hundreds of objects and the call to the function `Reflect.getProperty` and `setProperty` is taking quite some CPU time.

Is there a way to bypass the Reflect API without having to inject raw `javascript` inside my Haxe code ? (so it can also be used on other platforms than js)

So instead of doing this:

```
finalValue = Reflect.getProperty(object, propertyName);
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
finalValue = object[propertyName];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about going `untyped`?

```
    // set
    untyped object[propertyName] = 15;

    // get
    var value = untyped object[propertyName];
```

Try it yourself: http://try.haxe.org/#5b61e

> **Warn** Going untyped lets you omit the type system and is more error prone. If you use instances with Haxe properties (getter/setters) it might give unexpected results. That's why using `Reflect` is considered *safer*.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that as well but I guess this is the best solution so far.
Thanks for answering so quickly !

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when using "untyped" with properties that are getters/setters and standard properties, because the calls are slightly different.
eg:

```
// set
untyped object["set_" + propertyName] = 15;

// get
var value = untyped object["get_" + propertyName];
```

Typically what we do with our tween library is do a check up front when the property is mapped to see if it is a getter/setter and store this information for runtime use.